# C++ fixed size arrays vs multiple objects of same type

Tags: c++, c, micro-optimization

I was wondering whether (apart from the obvious syntax differences) there would be any efficiency difference between having a class containing multiple instances of an object (of the same type) or a fixed size array of objects of that type.

In code:

```
struct A {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};

struct B {
  double xvec[3];
};
```

In reality I would be using boost::arrays which are a better C++ alternative to C-style arrays.

I am mainly concerned with construction/destruction and reading/writing such doubles, because these classes will often be constructed just to invoke one of their member functions once.

Thank you for your help/suggestions.

Comment: arrays allow iteration over their values, which is not possible when using individual members

Comment: Whenever you have a question about efficiency/performance, write a little test-application and compare. If you have troubles interpreting the results, ask a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically the representation of those two structs would be exactly the same. It is, however, possible to have poor performance if you pick the wrong one *for your use case*.

For example, if you need to access each element in a loop, with an array you could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    dosomething(xvec[i]);
```

However, without an array, you'd either need to duplicate code:

```
dosomething(x);
dosomething(y);
dosomething(z);
```

This means code duplication - which can go either way. On the one hand there's less loop code; on the other hand very tight loops can be quite fast on modern processors, and code duplication can blow away the I-cache.

The other option is a switch:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int *r;
    switch(i) {
        case 0: r = &x; break;
        case 1: r = &y; break;
        case 1: r = &z; break;
    }
    dosomething(*r); // assume this is some big inlined code
}
```

This avoids the possibly-large i-cache footprint, but has a huge negative performance impact. Don't do this.

On the other hand, it is, in principle, possible for array accesses to be slower, if your compiler isn't very smart:

```
xvec[0] = xvec[1] + 1;
dosomething(xvec[1]);
```

Since xvec[0] and xvec[1] are distinct, in principle, the compiler ought to be able to keep the value of xvec[1] in a register, so it doesn't have to reload the value at the next line. However, it's possible some compilers might not be smart enough to notice that xvec[0] and xvec[1] don't alias. In this case, using seperate fields might be a very tiny bit faster.

In short, it's not about one or the other being fast in all cases. It's about matching the representation to how you use it.

Personally, I would suggest going with whatever makes the code working on xvec most natural. It's not worth spending a lot of human time worrying about something that, at best, will probably only produce such a small performance difference that you'll only catch it in micro-benchmarks.

Answer (score 5):

MVC++ 2010 generated exactly the same code for reading/writing from two POD structs like in your example. Since the offsets to read/write to are computable at compile time, this is not surprising. Same goes for construction and destruction.

As for the actual performance, the general rule applies: profile it if it matters, if it doesn't - why care?

Indexing into an array member is perhaps a bit more work for the user of your struct, but then again, he can more easily iterate over the elements.

Comment: Very interesting finding, thank you for reporting this! (I am using VS2010 as well :P)

Answer (score 2):

In case you can't decide and want to keep your options open, you can use an anonymous union:

```
struct Foo
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            double x;
            double y;
            double z;
        } xyz;
        double arr[3];
    };
};

int main()
{
    Foo a;
    a.xyz.x = 42;
    std::cout << a.arr[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Some compilers also support anonymous structs, in that case you can leave the `xyz` part out.

Comment: Although it's non-standard, support for anonymous unions is fairly common: both GCC and MSVC support them.  Anonymous unions have also been added to the upcoming C1X language standard, although that's a long ways off from being standardized and implemented (heck, C99 support is pretty pathetic as it is, and that standard is 12 years old already!).

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Anonymous unions are standard in C++, see 9.5.4

Answer (score 1):

It depends. For instance, the example you gave is a classic one in favor of 'old-school' arrays: a math point/vector (or matrix)

- has a fixed number of elements
- the data itself is usually kept
  private in an object
- since (if?) it has a class as an
  interface, you can properly
  initialize them in the constructor
  (otherwise, classic array
  inialization is something I don't
  really like, syntax-wise)

In such cases (going with the math vector/matrix examples), I always ended up using C-style arrays internally, as you can loop over them instead of writing copy/pasted code for each component.

But this is a special case -- for me, in C++ nowadays arrays == STL vector, it's fast and I don't have to worry about nuthin' :)

Comment: There's a difference between `std::vector<T>` and `std::array<T, n>`, so I wouldn't equate arrays with vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The difference can be in storing the variables in memory. In the first example compiler can add padding to align the data. But in your paticular case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

raw arrays offer better cache locality than c++ arrays, as presented however, the array example's only advantage over the multiple objects is the ability to iterate over the elements.

The real answer is of course, create a test case and measure.

Comment: C++ arrays are laid out in memory exactly like C arrays. A C++ array is just a struct with a single C array member.

Comment: I never measured this, but an STL vector should provide the same cache locality as a C array if used in the same fashion (ie. specify the no. of elements at init, and don't make it re-allocate memory by going over the 'limit').

Comment: You know - that is technically true. So perhaps I was being disingenuous. However, the logical consequence of using generic classes rather than raw native types does lead to the inevitable use of smart pointer and other wrapper objects.